# What happens when I gift someone a Battle pass who already owns it (fortnite BR)?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

If I try to gift a Battle Pass to a friend who already has one, will I lose V-Bucks and that person won't receive the Battle Pass or will I even be able to send the gift?

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Fortnite Help page](https://epicgames.helpshift.com/a/fortnite/?s=general-support&f=how-does-gifting-work-in-battle-royale) about gifting:

> If you’re trying to gift an item to a player who already has that item, gifting will fail.

However, the same page states Battle Passes aren't able to be given as gifts.

Comment: Battle Passes can be gifted, but only if you already own one.

Comment: @aytimothy I'm finding sources saying it was only available for gifting with the release of V10.00 (which was around the first week of August I believe?) until August 15th.  The [official patch notes](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/patch-notes/v10-00-patch-notes) state this.  Is this not the case?